# Ruby extension by FFI

Tags: c++, ruby, ffi

I have such, for example, C++ library with classes:

```
class Hello2

bool doSomething()
end

end

class Hello

  Hello2 getStatus()
{
  Hello2* hello2 = new Hello2();
  return hello2;
}

end
```

How can I map it by ffi (https://github.com/ffi/ffi)? Because its not static methods. I need something like this in ruby:

```
obj1 = Hello.new
obj2 = obj1.get_status
obj2.do_something
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a few links that may be helpful:

- https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/173158
- [rb++](http://rbplusplus.rubyforge.org/) a code generation tool for wrapping C++ APIs
- [Rice](http://rice.rubyforge.org) is a C++ interface to the Ruby API

Here's a link to a sample in rb++'s github repo:

https://github.com/jameskilton/rbplusplus/tree/master/samples/my_math